# Can I use multiple useState and useReducer with no side effect?

Tags: reactjs

I have three questions:

1. Can I use multiple useState right after another without side effects? I know that I can put these two values inside an object, but if I did not want to do that, is this possible without side effects? Like will it retrigger two renders?:

   ```
    useEffect(
      () => {
        setCount(count);
        setText(`Clicked ${count}`);
      },
      [count],
    );
   ```
2. The same question as above, but exchange the useState with useReducer:

   ```
     useEffect(
       () => {
         setCount({ type: 'onClick', count });
         setText({ type: 'onChangeText', text: `Clicked ${count}` });
       },
       [count],
     );
   ```
3. And also the same question but with one of each:

   ```
    useEffect(
       () => {
         setCount(count);
         setText({ type: 'onChangeText', text: `Clicked ${count}` });
       },
       [count],
     );
   ```

Comment: You can do it, re-rendering will be triggered once (all the other constraints applied) asynchronously after all your code has been executed.

Comment: Answer to all your questions is, Yes, you can do multiple state update calls next to each other.

React will batch the state update if they are triggered directly, like in your code. If you call the functions to update the state asynchronously, like wrapped in a promise, then in this case state updates won't be batched.

Comment: Yes, but because you are enqueueing multiple state updates within each render cycle and react batch processes them in the order they are enqueued, be sure to use functional state updates if *any* subsequent updates *depend* on previous state.

Comment: @DrewReese State updates (setting state or dispatching) are enqueued only when done synchronously in event handler or effect, when done after an asynchronous function they will not. The the setCount example would not cause updates anyway because the effect runs when count changes and it sets count to the current value, the example may as well do `setCount(count=>count)`. It doesn't cause change to state and doesn't cause an update even if it was asynchronous.

Comment: @HMR Thanks, but I didn't mention anything about asynchronous functions (nor did OP), but rather pointed out when multiple state updates are enqueued *within the same render cycle* **and** *depend on previous state* that a functional state update may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

All your examples will only render once because you do not set state or dispatch **after an async function**. If you were to do set state or dispatch after an async function you component would render on every set state or dispatch that causes a change in state.

Your examples are kind of poor though because why would you want to set count in an effect when count changed to the value of count? That is like doing: `setCount(count=>count)` and doesn't set anything nor cause a re render.

You can use `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates` to batch update multiple states or dispatch multiple actions but if these values are related then maybe you should combine them in state or create a reducer that will update both values at once.

Here is a demo showing multiple renders when setting state or dispatching multiple times after an async function. There are no multiple renders when unstable_batchedUpdates is used.

```js
const reducer = (state, action) => state + 1;
const useABC = () => {
  const [a, setA] = React.useState(0);
  const [b, setB] = React.useState(0);
  const [c, setC] = React.useState(0);
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, 0);

  const ref = React.useRef([]);
  const reducerRef = React.useRef([]);
  ref.current = ref.current.concat(
    `render:${ref.current.length + 1} a:${a} b:${b} c:${c}`
  );
  reducerRef.current = reducerRef.current.concat(
    `render:${
      reducerRef.current.length + 1
    } state:${state}, c:${c}`
  );
  const up = React.useCallback(
    () => setC((c) => c + 1),
    []
  );
  return [
    [setA, setB, up, c, ref],
    [state, dispatch, reducerRef],
  ];
};
const Output = React.memo(function Output({ up, c, r }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={up}>{c}</button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(r, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
});
//when c increases it causes one render
//  then when a is set to c it causes a render
//  then when b is set to c it causes a render
const SetState = () => {
  const [[setA, setB, up, c, ref]] = useABC();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      setA(c);
      setB(c);
    });
  }, [c, setA, setB]);
  return <Output c={c} up={up} r={ref.current} />;
};
//when c increases it causes one render
//  then when state is increased it causes a render
//  then when state is increased again it causes a render
const Reducer = () => {
  const [[, , up, c], [, dispatch, ref]] = useABC();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (c !== 0) {
      Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        dispatch();
        dispatch();
      });
    }
  }, [c, dispatch]);
  return <Output c={c} up={up} r={ref.current} />;
};
const BatchUpdated = () => {
  const [[setA, setB, up, c, ref]] = useABC();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      //using batch updated
      ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
        setA(c);
        setB(c);
      });
    });
  }, [c, setA, setB]);
  return <Output c={c} up={up} r={ref.current} />;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>batch updates</h1>
      <BatchUpdated />
      <h1>set state</h1>
      <SetState />
      <h1>reducer</h1>
      <Reducer />
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope you know what's happening when you update a state inside an effect that relys on it

here is the code sandbox, and think why it's showing `i=11`
[image]
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-ride-4rvci?file=/src/App.js

if you get the my point, you are free to use it, and take tare of infinite loop

and this is not good practice, if you don't need loop, just update other state or just use `count` or tmp vars from `count` in jsx; if you need loop, why not loop explictly and update final state after calculate